# how to put a kivy button in the middle? X coordinates not working

Tags: kivy

I've learnt kivy halfway and I've stopped using it for some time I've forgotten a little so anyway I've made a little project so-called a "Tally Counter" and I've wanted to add a button in the middle and little downwards - I've done it and suddenly the x coordinates were not working - heres the output -
[image: OUTPUT]

the code -

```
from kivy.core import window
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.lang import builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window
import os, sys
from kivy.resources import resource_add_path, resource_find

builder.Builder.load_file("tally.kv")
Window.size = (450,600)
class Tally(Widget):
    pass

        

class Count(App):
    def build(self):
        return Tally()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Count().run()
```

And last but not least the KV file

```
<Tally>
    BoxLayout:
        orientartion:"vertical"
        size: root.width,root.height
        Button:
            text:"Count"
            size_hint: (None, None)
            height: 70
            width: 400
            pos_hint: {"center_x":.5,"center_y":.3}
```

Yet I feel the guilt for forgetting kivy, I'm kind of stupid for asking these questions, I'll ask better questions from now on. I'll try my best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [BoxLayout Documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.boxlayout.html):

> Position hints are partially working, depending on the orientation:
>
> If the orientation is vertical: x, right and center_x will be used.
>
> If the orientation is horizontal: y, top and center_y will be used.

However, you have a typo in your `kv` file. Try changing:

```
orientartion:"vertical"
```

to:

```
orientation:"vertical"
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer this three button hope you find your solution from it

```
 # import modules
    import kivy
     
    # base Class of your App inherits from the App class.
    # app:always refers to the instance of your application
    from kivy.app import App
     
    # creates the button in kivy
    # if not imported shows the error
    from kivy.uix.button import Button
     
    # This layout allows you to set relative coordinates for children.
    from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
     
    # To change the kivy default settings
    # we use this module config
    from kivy.config import Config
         
    # 0 being off 1 being on as in true / false
    # you can use 0 or 1 && True or False
    Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', True)
     
    # creating the App class
    class Pos_Size_App(App):
         
        def build(self):
     
            # A Relative Layout with a size of (300, 300) is created
            rl = RelativeLayout(size =(300, 300))
             
            # creating button
            # size of button is 20 % by height and width of layout
            # position is 'center_x':.7, 'center_y':.5
            b1 = Button(size_hint =(.2, .2),
                        pos_hint ={'center_x':.7, 'center_y':.5},
                        text ="pos_hint")
     
            # creating button
            # size of button is 20 % by height and 50 % width of layout
            b2 = Button(size_hint =(.5, .2), 
                        text ="size_hint")
     
                    # creating button
            # size of button is 20 % by height and width of layout
            # position is 200, 200 from bottom left
            b3 = Button( size_hint =(.2, .2),
                        pos =(200, 200),
                        text ="pos")
             
             
     
            # adding button to widget
            rl.add_widget(b1)
            rl.add_widget(b2)
            rl.add_widget(b3)
         
             
            # returning widget
            return rl
     
    # run the App
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        Pos_Size_App().run()
```

Comment: doesn't work its closing